Why does `FullSimplify` sometimes return unequivalent expressions?
Define f1 and f2 as follows:
f2 = FullSimplify[
   f1 = (k3 \[RawLess] 
        0 \[And] ((-k3/4 \[LessSlantEqual] k1 \[LessSlantEqual] -k3/(2 - \[Sqrt]2) \[And] 
           k2 \[GreaterSlantEqual] (k3 - Sqrt[-k3 (4 k1 + k3)])/
            2) \[Or] (k1 \[RawGreater] -k3/(2 - \[Sqrt]2) \[And] 
           k2 \[GreaterSlantEqual] k3 - (\[Sqrt]2 - 1) k1))) \[Or] (k3 \[LongEqual] 
        0 \[And] ((k1 \[LongEqual] 0 \[And] k2 \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0) \[Or] (k1 \[RawGreater] 0 \[And] 
           k2 \[GreaterSlantEqual] -(\[Sqrt]2 - 1) k1))) \[Or] (k3 \[RawGreater] 
        0 \[And] ((-k3/4 \[LessSlantEqual] k1 \[LessSlantEqual] 0 \[And] 
           k2 \[GreaterSlantEqual] k3 - (\[Sqrt]2 - 1) k1) \[Or] (k1 \[RawGreater] 0 \[And] 
           k2 \[GreaterSlantEqual] k3 - (\[Sqrt]2 - 1) k1))), {k1, k3, k2} \[Element] 
    Reals];

We can see that they are not equivalent:
Resolve[ForAll[{k1, k3, k2}, f2 \[Equivalent] f1], Reals]

(*False*)

But if we simply swap k2 and k3,
g2 = FullSimplify[
   g1 = f1 /. Thread[{k3, k2} \[Rule] {k2, k3}], {k1, k2, k3} \[Element] 
    Reals];

the two results will be equivalent:
Resolve[ForAll[{k1, k2, k3}, g2 \[Equivalent] g1], Reals]

(*True*)

So why did FulSimplify get it incorrect in the former case (in Wolfram 14.1.0)?

DictionaryLookup[__ ~~ "equivalent"]

It is either a bug in FullSimplify or in Resolve.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f2 = FullSimplify[
   f1 = (k3 < 
        0 \[And] ((-k3/4 <= k1 <= -k3/(2 - \[Sqrt]2) \[And] 
           k2 >= (k3 - Sqrt[-k3 (4 k1 + k3)])/
             2) \[Or] (k1 > -k3/(2 - \[Sqrt]2) \[And] 
           k2 >= k3 - (\[Sqrt]2 - 1) k1))) \[Or] (k3 == 
        0 \[And] ((k1 == 0 \[And] k2 >= 0) \[Or] (k1 > 0 \[And] 
           k2 >= -(\[Sqrt]2 - 1) k1))) \[Or] (k3 > 
        0 \[And] ((-k3/4 <= k1 <= 0 \[And] 
           k2 >= k3 - (\[Sqrt]2 - 1) k1) \[Or] (k1 > 0 \[And] 
           k2 >= k3 - (\[Sqrt]2 - 1) k1))), {k1, k3, k2} \[Element] Reals];

rgn1 = ImplicitRegion[f1, {k1, k2, k3}];

rgn2 = ImplicitRegion[f2, {k1, k2, k3}];

The regions are equal
RegionEqual[rgn1, rgn2]

(* True *)

That is, each region contains the other
And @@ RegionWithin @@@ {{rgn1, rgn2}, {rgn2, rgn1}}

(* True *)

